# Appium grid org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find

Tags: java, selenium, web-applications, grid, appium

Appium (version 1.18.3) grid is throwing error while executing Chrome-based web app testing.

Chrome.java class

```
package com.example.appium;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Optional;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Chrome {
    WebDriver driver;
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    @BeforeClass
    public void init() throws MalformedURLException {
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "ZH33L2Z6KL");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
        cap.setCapability("chromeDriverPort", "8201");
        cap.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable","C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1");
    }

    @Test
    public void testApp() {
        try {
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");
    }
}
```

TestNG XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Regression" thread-count="2" parallel="tests" preserve-order="true" verbose="2">
    <test name="Real Device1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.example.appium.Chrome"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Appium selenium-grid is invoked by using the commands:

Hub:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
```

nodeconfig_device1.json:

```
{
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "browserName": "Chrome",
      "version": "6.0",
      "maxInstances": 10,      
      "deviceName": "ZH33L2Z6KL",
      "platformName": "ANDROID",
      "automationName":"UiAutomator2",
      "chromeDriverPort":"8201"
    }
  ],
  "configuration": {
    "cleanUpCycle": 2000,
    "timeout": 300000,
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",    
    "maxSession": 10,        
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": "192.168.0.105",
    "hubProtocol":"http"
  }
}
```

node1 is invoked using the command:

```
appium --port 6001 --nodeconfig nodeconfig_device1.json
```

The following error is thrown when Chrome apk is invoked:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: Chrome, chromeDriverPort: 6001, chromedriverExecutable: C:\chromedriver\chromedrive..., deviceName: ZH33L2Z6KL, platformName: android, version: 5.1}
Command duration or timeout: 282 milliseconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:54)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at com.example.appium.Chrome.testApp(Chrome.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:40)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:489)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$1.call(ThreadUtil.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: Chrome, chromeDriverPort: 6001, chromedriverExecutable: C:\chromedriver\chromedrive..., deviceName: ZH33L2Z6KL, platformName: android, version: 5.1}
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-E205GQ8', ip: '192.168.0.105', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_261'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:118)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:85)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:69)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Note:

This code is working perfectly when Appium GUI (Version 1.18.3) is invoked, with IP address is set to 127.0.0.1 and port is set 4723.
This time, Driver is changed as follows:

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
```

Questions:

1. Why Appium grid is not invoking Chrome app in Android device?
2. Why 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find' error is thrown, even though the chrome app and chrome driver are not having any conflict?
3. Are any additional settings required?